# how to draw words using python turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a code where turtle draws words you type into it using idle python and it is drawing the letters out I alphabetical order(bc that's the order I have coded it) and I don't know how to change it. plz help! help would be appreciated.(I know there is only 3 letters I haven't had time to code in more.[here is the code](https://samduncliffe9.wixsite.com/idlepythoncode)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're asking how to change it, but in what way? What is your goal?

Comment: @ggorlen Do not copy code from an external site into posts (reference [1](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512), [2](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698)), unless *you have verified* that the license under which the original source of the code permits copying *and* that license is compatible with re-releasing the code under CC BY-SA 3.0 (the license Stack Exchange uses). Copying code, as you did here, is usually a copyright violation. Note: even the authorization of the OP is insufficient, because you have no way to know they are the actual copyright holder. Copying code needs to be left to the OP.

Comment: In this case, the linked page indicates no license (at least none that I saw looking at the page, the page source or trying to go to the root of the sub-domain). Thus, copying, is not permitted.

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new every day.

Comment: sorry about any copyright issues I just made the website to show my code so people could answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a simple fix, you should define `space, a, b` and `c` as functions and then call them in the order you got from the text.

```
print ("Hello and welcome to word drawing")
text = input ("Enter your text you want to print:")
selectedcolour = input ("What colour would you like it?")
thick = input ("How thick would you like it? (min:1 max:100)")

import turtle
forward=turtle.forward
back=turtle.backward
right=turtle.right
left=turtle.left
pup=turtle.penup
pdown=turtle.pendown
colour=turtle.color
thickness=turtle.width

colour(selectedcolour)
thickness(thick)
pup()
left(180)
forward(400)
left(180)
pdown()

def space():
    pup()
    forward(100)
    pdown()

def a():
    for i in range(450): #this is an A
        forward(2)
        left(1)
    forward(140)
    right(180)
    forward(240)
    for i in range(90):
        forward(1)
        left(1)
    pup()
    forward(100)
    left(90)
    forward(25)
    right(90)
    pdown()

def b():
    left(90)
    forward(300)
    back(250)
    for i in range(180):
        forward(3)
        right(2)
    back(100)
    pup()
    right(90)
    forward(300)
    pdown()

def c():
    pup()
    forward(100)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    right(90)
    pdown()
    right(135)
    for i in range(275):
        forward(2)
        right(1)
    pup()
    right(45)
    forward(200)
    left(90)
    forward(100)
    pdown()

draw = {" ":space, "a":a, "b":b, "c":c}

for letter in text:
    if letter in draw.keys():
        draw[letter]()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#other letters                                                             
def d():
    left(90)
    forward(300)
    back(250)  
    for i in range(180):
        forward(3)
        left(2)
    back(100)
    pup()
    left(90)
    forward(300)
    pdown()

def e():
    forward(100)
    back(100)
    left(90)
    forward(100)
    left(90)
    back(100)
    forward(100)
    right(90)
    forward(100)
    right(90)
    forward(100)

def f():
    left(90)
    forward(100)
    right(90)
    forward(100)
    back(100)
    forward(100)
    back(100)
    left(90)
    forward(100)
    right(90)
    forward(100)
def g():
    left(90)
    forward(70)
    left(90)
    forward(70)
    left(90)
    forward(63)
    left(90)
    pdown()
    right(135)
    for i in range(275):
        forward(2)
        right(1)
    pup()
```